# General Install Procedure

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm a new and interested user.  I have an older inspiron mini with windows 7 that doesn't have enough RAM to do anything so I thought I would give Ubuntu a try.  I was able to download the image file and place it on the flash drive.  I also modified the BIOS and got it to boot from the USB.  Now I am in Grub4DOS and have no idea what to do next.  I think I am missing a big part.  Please help!

Comment: What did you use to create the USB?

Answer (score 0):

As you have an "older Inspiron" I would recommend using the `wubi installer`. I used it myself and it worked just fine.

wubi installer: --> [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

And if you decide to continue your installation here's the guide: [Ubuntu Installation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)